# Returning the result of multiple shell commands in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So what I'm trying to do is loop over an array of javascript objects (`sensors`), each with `cmd` and `parser` attributes, run each `cmd` in the system shell, parse its output with the  appropriate `parser` function, and append the resulting string to the server's `res` object.

The first issue is that I get an error claiming the current object has no method `parser`. I've tried a few different things and still can't get it to recognize that attribute of the object.

The second issue, when I gave up and hardcoded the parse function inside the loop (which destroys my ability to add commands that need a different parser), is that because the output of each command is read in a callback function, the server runs `res.end()` before the callbacks return, causing an empty response to the browser.

I'm quite new to node and javascript, so I'm sure I've made some beginner mistakes, I just can't seem to sort them out in my head. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// requires
var http = require('http');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// parsers
var parseTemp = function(str) {
    return ((parseInt(str, 16) / 50 - 273.15).toFixed(2));
};

// sensors
var sensors = [
    {
        label:  "Object temp",
        cmd:    "i2cget -y 3 0x5a 0x07 w",
        parser: parseTemp,
        units:  " degrees C"
    },
    {
        label:  "Ambient temp",
        cmd:    "i2cget -y 3 0x5a 0x06 w",
        parser: parseTemp,
        units:  " degrees C"
    }
];

// server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    for (var s in sensors) {
        exec(s.cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            res.write( s.label + ': ' + s.parser(stdout) + s.units + '\n' );
        });
    }
    res.end();
}).listen(1337, '');

console.log('Server running on port 1337');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is a result of each callback function referencing the same `s` variable. You can easily solve this by changing the `for(s in sensors)` loop into a `sensors.forEach(function(s){...})`. That will close over (google javascript closure) the s and make it the right one for each callback when the time comes. There might be other problems - I didn't look all that hard once I saw this issue.

Your second issue is precisely what you said. The `res.end()` is being called before the callbacks - since they're asynchronous, so at best will be called after the current "thread" of execution is finished. You can solve that with a simple counter: increment before every `exec` call, and on each callback decrement and check if the counter has reached its initial value - if so, then run `res.end()`.